# what are some of the industry wide used continous integration tool , nightly build system for Python based program

Tags: python, testing, automation, continuous-integration, nightly-build

what are some of the industry wide used continuos integration tool , nightly build system for Python based program.

We want to automate the a lot of manual testing and then use daily running system to test automatically.
We are using Pyunit for writing unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Buildbot](http://trac.buildbot.net/) is written in python/twisted, and all of it's configuration syntax is in python, so it's very easy for python programmers to setup.  A bunch of [open source projects use it](http://trac.buildbot.net/wiki/SuccessStories) including [python itself](http://www.python.org/dev/buildbot/).

Personally, I think it's UI leaves something to be desired compared to Jenkins/Hudson, but it's functionality is fantastic.

Answer (score 4):

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (forked from [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) after it was bought by Oracle), despite being written originally for Java, has a significant following in the Python community.

There are even a number of tutorials:

- http://jenkins-ci.org/content/python-love-story-virtualenv-and-hudson
- http://jenkins-ci.org/content/screencast-python-hudson-part-1

Answer (score 0):

We have a reasonably large project all in python, we're using github for version control with buildbot as our nightly build system. http://trac.buildbot.net/  It works really well except when you get called out in the "blamelist"